# a random variable on [0,1]

Tags: probability-theory

If I have a random variable 
$$ X:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\quad \text{so that} \quad
 X(w)=\min\{w,1-w\} , \quad \text{ where } w \in [0,1]$$
The question is to find the following  preimage:
$$ X^{-1}(]-\infty,x]=\varnothing\quad \text{ if } x<0
$$
$$ [0,x]\bigcup[1-x,1] \quad\text { if }  0<=x<=1/2
$$
$$ [0,1] \quad\text     {if }  x>=1/2 $$

Does someone know how did he calculate it?

Comment: Please improve the matematical notation with MathJax. I got you started and you can continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only find this CDF if the probability on $[0,1]$ is known to you, but you do not mention it in your question.

Start with:$$\begin{aligned}F_{X}\left(x\right) & =P\left(X\leq x\right)\\
 & =1-P\left(X>x\right)\\
 & =1-P\left(\left\{ w\in\left[0,1\right]\mid\min\left\{ w,1-w\right\} >x\right\} \right)\\
 & =1-P\left(\left\{ w\in\left[0,1\right]\mid x<w<1-x\right\} \right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Now proceed by discerning cases for $x$.

---

**edit**:

By definition:$$X^{-1}((-\infty,x])=\{w\in[0,1]\mid X(w)\in(-\infty,x]\}=\{w\in [0,1]\mid\min\{w,1-w\}\leq x\}$$

First observe that $0\leq\min\{w,1-w\}\leq\frac12$ for every $w\in[0,1]$.

Now we will discern possible values of $x$:

- If $x<0$ then *no* $w\in[0,1]$ exists that satisfies $\min\{w,1-w\}\leq x$ so in that case the preimage is empty.
- If $x>\frac12$ then *every* $w\in[0,1]$ satisfies  $\min\{w,1-w\}\leq x$ so in that case the preimage is $[0,1]$.
- If $x\in[0,\frac12]$ then it is handsome to split up:
  $$\begin{aligned}X^{-1}\left(\left(-\infty,x\right]\right) & =\left\{ w\in\left[0,1\right]\mid\min\left\{ w,1-w\right\} \leq x\right\} \\
   & =\left\{ w\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\mid w\leq x\right\} \cup\left\{ w\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\mid1-w\leq x\right\} \\
   & =\left\{ w\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\mid w\leq x\right\} \cup\left\{ w\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\mid w\geq1-x\right\} \\
   & =\left[0,x\right]\cup\left[1-x,1\right]
  \end{aligned}
  $$

Comment: $X^{-1}$ does not denote an inverse here. In general if $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ and $B\subseteq\mathbb R$ then $X^{-1}(B)$ denotes the following subset of $\Omega$: the set $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in B\}$. That is the so-called *preimage of set $B$ under function* $X$.

Comment: i edited my ques ,can u plz answer it?

Comment: You stlll speak of *inverse* in your question. As I said: we are not dealing with an inverse.

Comment: i edited it now

Comment: I have edited also.